# What should be done with the "grammar-checker" tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[grammar-checker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-checker) seems a misused tag; in some cases, it seems more appropriate to use [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality).

Should we remove [grammar-checker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-checker), or does the tag have a purpose and we should write the Wiki page for it?

Comment: This appears to be long ago taken care of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two are the only questions tagged [grammar-checker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-checker) that actually belong there:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2993/1547
- [Microsoft Word's "fragments"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1120/1547)

And of those, the first would arguably be closed if it were asked today.

The other questions in the tag either belong under [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality), or somewhere else entirely (judging by all the [closed] questions).

I think it would be best to remove the grammar-checker tag altogether, because it's not serving much of a purpose other than to confuse people.

Comment: I have removed the tag from all the 14 questions, including the closed questions, and one that was just asking what an hyphen is. (I wonder in which way that is related with a grammar checker.)